# Yii2 and bootstrap field behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components, bootstrap-popover

Is it possible to modify the behaviur that an ActiveField in Yii2 has?

Yii2 has a default template to create and display input tags along with their errors/hints etc.

```
string $template = "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
```

If i create a field as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput() ?>
```

using the above template, the label will be displayed followed by the input tag and the error tag (hint is optional).

But using bootstrap i want to display the error in a [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) and not in the error tag which is generated. and if there are no errors, then a default message appear in the popover like "what is your email address?"

Thanks :)

Comment: What you have already tried?

Comment: i was trying to see if it's possible to do it with already available functions of ActiveField, but seems can't be done like this.. i think it might be done bt manipulating the template or by creating another inputwidget... any other ideas??

Comment: why dont you add a class for error hints and other stuff handle with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

well i'm change `.has-error` position from the site.css `"{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"`

```
.has-error input{
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.11119);
}
.has-error > .help-block {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1vh;
    margin-top: -9.2vh;    
}
```

with this you well change this

[image: default Yii2 Error]

For this:

[image: My css]